# Getting an error in my Postgresql database due to an issue with Postgis (Can't find $libdir/postgis-2.0?)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I randomly started getting this error today when I try to select from a column that holds a geometry value

ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0"

My selects have been working fine before, but this just started happening today. Any tips on how to fix this? I have been keeping my linux server up-to-date if that effects anything.

This error appears when I load up pgadmin as well as conducting select queries on this certain column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, clearly "something changed". You need to find out what your libdir setting is now and why it no longer has postgis-2.0

This manual page discusses the $libdir setting and how to check it
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html

Can't tell you how to check your postgis installation without knowing how you installed it.

Assuming the directory is there, but called something else - try making a symlink. Likewise if it now has a different location.

Long-term solution is to dump the database as SQL (not custom format), edit the schema paths to whatever the new ones are and restore it.

Although you don't provide any details, I'm guessing your package manager has changed how/where the postgresql extensions get stored.